# Returning Column Name from Matrix based on value in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that I want to extract column names based on the value.  In this case I want the name of any column that contains a value less than or equal to 2 (doesnt matter what row that value is located in).

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- matrix(sample(1:9,9),ncol=3,nrow=3)
DF <- as.data.frame.matrix(DF)
```

this is what I have tried, (it seems to work if there is only 1 row in the matrix)

```
test<-colnames(DF)[which(DF<=2),]
```

test would then represent the column names containing values <= 2

Comment: I have also tried 'test<-colnames(DF)[DF<=2]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1

Run `sapply` over columns and find `min` and then check if the `min` meets your condition.

```
colnames(DF)[sapply(DF, min) <= 2]
#[1] "V3"
```

## 2

You can also run `apply` on columns (`MARGIN = 2`) to see if `any` value in each column meets the required condition

```
colnames(DF)[apply(DF, MARGIN = 2, function(a) any(a<=2))]
#[1] "V3"
```

## 3

Use `arr.ind = TRUE` with `which`. This will give the indices of the values that meet the condition of `which`. From that, extract the column information `[,2]`.

```
unique(colnames(DF)[which(DF<=2, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]])
#[1] "V3"
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- matrix(sample(1:9,9),ncol=3,nrow=3)
DF <- as.data.frame.matrix(DF)
DF
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  9  5  6
#2  8  4  1
#3  3  7  2
```

Comment: thanks@d.b is there a way to make it so each column name is only returned 1 time?

Comment: Or another option is `unique(names(DF)[col(DF)*(DF <= 2)])#
[1] "V3"`

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `colMins/rowMins` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
names(DF)[rowMins(t(DF))<=2]
#[1] "V3"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(min(.) <=2)) %>% 
    unlist %>% 
    names(.)[.]
#[1] "V3"
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't need any `apply` loops.  We can take the unique values of the result of `col()` when used on the condition `DF <= 2`.

```
names(DF)[unique(col(DF)[DF <= 2])]
# [1] "V3"
```